# Email sent from Lead is counting under daily limit

Tags: email, governorlimits, limits, singleemailmessage

I was going through the salesforce document [Daily Allocations for Email Alerts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits_email.htm&type=5) It is mentioned that There’s no limit on sending single emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your org directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.
I tried sending email directly from Lead record but it is counting under the daily limit.

Any help will be appreciated

I have attached the screenshots from where I am sending email-[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to this:

> There’s no limit on sending single emails to contacts, leads, person
>   accounts, and users in your org directly **from** account, contact, lead,
>   opportunity, case, campaign, or **custom object pages**.

Then the highlighted part is crucially important. There's no limit to a user going to the page and sending an email manually.

The limits still counts for Apex sending `SingleEmailMessage` objects.

Intuitively, this makes sense because Apex could sends vast amounts of email and be spamming or using lots of resources.

Users manually sending from pages just can't do the volume to cause issues, so SF don't limit it.

**Addition, it seems to be different for Scratch Orgs**

Ajay came back and showed more detail. Which implies that he's trying this on a scratch org. I've tried on a scratch org, and had the same result as him: sending an email from the object page, even in Classic used up one of my email limit. But, it does not do this in a conventional sandbox.

Comment: Hi Aidan, Thanks for your reply. Actually, I considered the highlighted part and tried to send email manually from the lead record itself but it is counting under the daily limit. I verified through workbench.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I think it's something specific to scratch orgs (see my edit) but I can't find any documentation to confirm

Comment: Hi Aidan, You are right. I was trying in developer org. Now I tried in Sandbox and it didn't counted under limit. Thanks.